# How to get all dates of given month from the list of dates in strings with python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to get all the dates with given year-month but it give incorrect results. What could be the better way to get all dates on given year-month?

```
d = ['2006-12-30', '2006-12-31', '2006-1-1', '2006-11-30', '2006-10-1','2006-9-30'] 

key = '2006-1'
[i for i in d if key in i]
```

It gives output

```
['2006-12-30', '2006-12-31', '2006-1-1', '2006-11-30', '2006-10-1']
```

while I need

```
['2006-1-1']
```

Advance thanks for any help?

Comment: Have you used debugger? What was result?

Answer (score 4):

Change your key from `2006-1` to `2006-1-`

```
>>> d = ['2006-12-30', '2006-12-31', '2006-1-1', '2006-11-30', '2006-10-1','2006-9-30'] 
>>> key = '2006-1-'
>>> [i for i in d if key in i]
['2006-1-1']
```

But a better way to do that would be to convert the string to `datetime` object and then make the decision

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> [i for i in d if datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m') == '2006-01']
['2006-1-1']
```

Comment: Even though this works in this particular usecase, I think I'd prefer to use regex or actual date objects

Comment: how I could use regex or date object for this usecase? Any guid?

Comment: @BilalZaib I have updated the answer with an example of how to use datetime for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a nicer way but that checks for all dates between the 01.01.2006 and the 31.01.2006

```
import datetime

d = ['2006-12-30', '2006-12-31', '2006-1-1', '2006-11-30', '2006-10-1','2006-9-30'] 

dates_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in d]

low = datetime.datetime.strptime('2006-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
up = datetime.datetime.strptime('2006-01-31', '%Y-%m-%d').date()


within = [date for date in dates_list if low <= date <= up]

print(within)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case `2006-1` is in both `2006-1` and `2006-12`.That's why you're not getting your expected answer.

You can try this:

```
d = ['2006-12-30', '2006-12-31', '2006-1-1', '2006-11-30', '2006-10-1','2006-9-30'] 
key = '2006-1'
output= [i for i in d if i.split("-")[0]==key.split("-")[0] and i.split("-")[1]==key.split("-")[1]]
print(output)
```

Comment: Why downvoting?